# Why do people love to downvote my questions?

Tags: discussion, downvote-reason

Is my English bad?

Do I not provide enough information?

Am I rude?

Should I already know an answer before I ask question here?

I ask questions because I don't know their answer. If I knew or if I was all-expert, I wouldn't have come to Stack Overflow for asking in the first place; instead I would've been helping others.

Please check my questions.

For instance, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50524834) is not an hour old yet. *(Edit: Someone upvoted this question.)*

I am tired of trying to word them better. Where is the problem? Reputation doesn't matter to me. Whenever I think about asking questions, I think about if I am contributing, but I fail.

If you can give me an advice about how should I improve my questions, I'd love to try it in my next question. Please quote the question you're trying to help me improve as well.

Comment: The problem I could see with the linked question is that it is based on a wrong premise and that it shows a lack of understanding what iterators are. You somehow assume that remove removes the item only from the iterator but not from the list and that resetting an iterator would magically bring back items. It is also unclear why you would want the items back? The whole point of removing them is not to have them in the next iteration.

Comment: If you can only see the few downvotes and can't enjoy the many upvotes you got then SO is not the right place to hang your hat.  There are plenty of social sites that only permit "likes", SO is just not one of them.

Comment: I have no comment or vote on the SO question - I would defer to the Java developers who voted on it.  I do, however, dislike hostile and unwelcoming titles like 'Why do people love to downvote my questions?' that imply an immoral/malicious intent to downvoting.  It's meta, so I would not flag or vtc, but still, it's yet another unjustified stab at SO curators:(

Comment: @BDL "*want the items back*" I didn't say that. Question is asked if one doesn't know its answer. My main strategy was to reset the iterator. But, iterator didn't have  a method like `reset()` or `startAgain()` in its documentation. Hence, I asked.

Comment: @Moritz Just frustration. All my questions get downvoted for first two days. Then, later they get upvoted as some users find them helpful.

Comment: @HansPassant I know this. Thanks. This is the reason of upvotes: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368571/why-do-people-love-to-downvote-my-questions?noredirect=1#comment594445_368571

Comment: Sure. But you don't ask "How do I reset the iterator". You ask "How do I reset the iterator because that will bring back items removed". And this is impossible and does not make sense at all.

Comment: @MartinJames I am sorry.

Comment: @BDL Sir, it was possible before I had the answer. I thought `remove()` removes from iteration queue, not the list.

Answer (score 5):

You provide a snippet which is very good.

You provide a description of what you want, very eloquently a bit hard to read and follow, but okay.

Now, where's your question?

One really has to study your eloquent description of what does what to glean what a possible question could be or your problem.

Please add in the future a concise, max two sentences question that summarizes what your question is or the problem you wish to resolve.

Like:

> How can I iterate the same list again after removing some claimed items?

I could see the lack of a clear "question"  being a reason for people to downvote. 
They don't deem the question bad enough to vote to close as unclear what you're asking, but they deem it low quality enough to downvote.

If you hover over the downvote arrow you see this(empahsis mine)

> This question does not show any research effort; **it is unclear** or not useful

Comment: This is what I do *not* understand. Why is vote-to-close (VTC) considered worse than downvote (DV)? I personally VTC for unclear questions by default and only DV if I think the question has absolutely no chance of being answered. Here there is a clear chance of it being answered as, in fact, it was (successfully, twice).

Comment: But the title said it. Also, my question "*How can I reset itemIterator to position 0 without reinitiating it using items.iterator() because that will bring back items removed from itemIterator for next iteration.*" is a two-liner in the question.

Comment: @rupinderjeet Yes, but in general the title is really only read when clicking on the link but not when reading the question. The flow of text is downwards, not upwards. It wouldn't have hurt to repeat the question at the bottom of your question after your snippet and explanation. People don't naturally jump back to the title in a flash of that was the question.

Comment: @jpp Sometimes a question is unclear enough to warrant a downvote as a signal op should improve his question, but not unclear enough to warrant a close vote. A close vote may be perceived as "This question is so unclear, it should be removed and I doubt op can salvage this trainwreck of a question" to put it in black and white terms. 
It made OP post this question so one could think the downvote has served it's purpose without being overly hard on OP.

Comment: @Tschallacka If someone doesn't have enough to time to read and understand a question like this, they're probably not fit to answer the question too.

Comment: Okay, lets turn this around: You are asking people to sacrifice their valueable time, that sometimes gets billed between 50-100 euros per hour, to read your question, understand it and answer it, for free/fake internet points. In return you can do your utmost best to make your question as clear and understandable as possible, helping people read your question and understand your question. If you don't like that you can always hire a professional to solve your problem for the above rates.

Comment: This logic of yours will not let open-source exist. We ask here looking for an answer. But, when we are answering it, we need to read the question to understand it. It is not "*Read the first line and assume the problem*". This service is free, you benefit from it too. If someone is annoyed that they're not getting paid for free/fake points, they shouldn't bother.

Comment: Your answer said that I didn't mention my question inside my question post. I explained you that in my first comment showing where my question is. Doesn't that mean that you yourself didn't read the question, and instead just assumed the problem.

Comment: @rupinderjeet: why are you arguing with Tschallacka? You asked for reasons, and he gave you back valid reasons. Please understand that he is telling you how others see your questions from their point of view, and please understand that he is correct.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Why is this being viewed as arguments? This question has a tag for discussion. And please, valid reasons? My question is in that post. I read questions before answering, rather than being fast enough for internet points.

Comment: @rupinderjeet: you are disagreeing with and debating his points. Understand that 1) they are valid, and 2) it is your responsibility as question asker to make it as easy as possible for volunteers to be able to understand the questions and then answer them.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I know that his intent is not about criticising me or my question. I merely want to discuss what is in my mind and how it is not getting to other people when they read my question. Your first point is just asking me to shush the discussion. For your second point, please post an answer and word my question better.

Comment: I don't have time for word-for-word as it is 6:30 AM and I am heading to work, but I do wish you the best of luck.

Comment: 'please post an answer and word my question better'..... What? You already have Sayse who did that. What is the value in another person using (wasting?) Their free volunteer time if all you'll do is disagree with their points?

Comment: @Patrice "*I'm trying to do foo*" implies that I need to explain what I am doing. I did. "*when iteratorA does X*" I explained what happened. "*What can I do to fix it so that when X happens*" I have my question in the post. I haven't posted this question on meta just to complain, I asked for improvements to my questions. The suggested improvements, to my thinking, appeared to be invalid.

Comment: Other example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49665845

Comment: You were asking to do something that is impossible, suggesting that you didn't adequately research the problem before asking.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thank you for your input. :)

Answer (score 3):

The question you've linked looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.. Even if it wasn't an XY problem the amount of times you're using the word "iterator" for so many different things makes it slightly confusing for what you are hoping to get the code to do.

Make sure your questions follow guidelines on the How to Ask page and don't worry about the odd downvote. If you get one, use it as a reason to relook at your question to see if it really is answerable in its current state or if there's anything that could be improved. For instance, add research effort. Simply adding "I looked at `[this question](so link)` which is close to what I want, but it's using `foo` so it won't work for me, because `bar` doesn't work well with it" would improve it dramatically, because it shows your research effort (which the lack of possibly makes me consider downvoting more than anything else), and it gives me other resources to look at which might explain what your end goal actually is.

---

## Rewrite attempt

I'm trying to do `foo` and the code below is used to the `bar` part of this task.

`<code></code>`

The problem is that when `iteratorA` does `X`, I need to reiterate over `iteratorB` but instead, it stays at its current iteration point.

What can I do to fix it so that when `X` happens, I can reiterate?

Comment: Please edit this answer to word my question better as an example. Keep your count on "iterator".

Comment: @rupinderjeet - I've had a go.. (Disclaimer: I know next to nothing about Java). Keep it precise and to the point, Explain what the code is supposed to be doing, what the problem is, and what you want it to do. (I've also omitted the point where i show what i've researched for brevity)

Comment: I appreciate your attempt. If I wanted to try this rewrite of yours and ask this question right now, do you think there will be downvotes and comments like "*this is not clear enough?*" and "*explain more*" and "*what are you trying to do?*". If you think this would be a good question to ask, I will ask it right now.

Comment: First, "explain more" isn't a bad comment (provided it explains what needs explaining more), and if you expand on `foo` enough to state what you are trying to do (whilst keeping it to the point) then that becomes mute. The important part is that you separate the actual question away from your own attempt(s) to solve the problem but both are equally important

Comment: Take a look at some of my [newer questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1324033/sayse?tab=questions&sort=newest) if you'd like to see more examples of what I'd say are written quite well

Comment: Expanding on `foo` makes more `iterator` words appear. It is nice that you tried to hide it that way. I will learn better wording from your questions, thanks.

Comment: @rupinderjeet - Your usage of iterator was all about your attempt to solve a problem, none of them were about what the task was that you were trying to accomplish, if you do end up asking it again, feel free to return here with a link to that question and if i find time i'll take a look if need be

Comment: The title mentioned what I wanted. Also, my question "*How can I reset itemIterator to position 0 without reinitiating it using items.iterator() because that will bring back items removed from itemIterator for next iteration.*" is what I wanted to accomplish. Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: I tend to only read titles to click on a question but once i've clicked on it and read the content i've normally forgotten what the title was so I wouldn't rely on that

Comment: So, you mean a title can basically be abused? If I write my problem is X in title, and say that my problem is Y in question description, that wouldn't be just ok because some users **remember**.